# Is the kilobyte used by time and ulimit commands either 1000 (SI) or 1024 (old school) bytes?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, ulimit, resource-limiting

From `man time`:

```
M      Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kilobytes.
```

From `ulimit -a`:

```
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
```

But a ["kilobyte" may mean either 1000 or 1024 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte).  I guess here it is a round 1024, but I want to be sure.  Authoritative reference would be appreciated.

Feel free to rephrase my question as: *do `time` and `ulimit` conform to the IEC recommendation, or use "kilobyte/kbyte" in the kibibyte meaning*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, kilobytes is 1000. We follow the [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) so the prefix "kilo" refers to 1000 not 1024. Any other reference is wrong.

1024 is [Kibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units) (**ki**lo **bi**nary)

> From ulimit -a:
>
> max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited

This I consider a bug. It should explicity state kilo or kibi; not kbytes

> man time:
>
> M      Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kilobytes.

- [ulimit](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/posix/ulimit.c.html) uses KIBIbytes

  ```
  limit.rlim_cur = newlimit * 512;
  limit.rlim_max = newlimit * 512;
  ```
- [GNU time](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/time.git/tree/src/rusage-kb.c#n46) usus KIBIbytes if you look at the source. The manual is wrong.

  It uses:

  ```
  tmp = pages / 1024;  /* Smaller first, */
  size = tmp / 1024;    /* then smaller.  */
  ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139085/discussion-on-answer-by-rinzwind-is-the-kilobyte-used-by-time-and-ulimit-command).

Answer (score 9):

Per [`man dir.1`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dir.1.html):

```
The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024). Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).
```

Per [`info ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html):

```
‘-h’
‘--human-readable’
Append a size letter to each size, such as ‘M’ for mebibytes. Powers of 1024 are used, not 1000; ‘M’ stands for 1,048,576 bytes. This option is equivalent to --block-size=human-readable. Use the --si option if you prefer powers of 1000.
```

The output for `ls` is further backed up in the source [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/8fdf9307b6e8e9b4d46e439237eb85d52caab85c/src/ls.c#L861) and [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/8fdf9307b6e8e9b4d46e439237eb85d52caab85c/src/ls.c#L2258).

It would seem as though the single letter is the 1024 measurement. The two <del>digit</del> character abbreviations are the 1000 SI units.

Since `ulimit` is builtin to bash, going to their source is the definitive...source. I'm often punny, but you can see it [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def?h=bash-5.2-rc3#n66) and [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def?h=bash-5.2-rc3#n264):

```
Values are in 1024-byte increments, except for -t, which is in seconds,
-p, which is in increments of 512 bytes, and -u, which is an unscaled
number of processes.
```

Your version is probably older than the bash-5.2-rc3, which is fine, the size of that item hasn't changed in at least the last decade since 4.0.38 was released. You can see it [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def?h=bash-4.0.38#n60) and [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def?h=bash-4.0.38#n234).

Edit: the man page for `units.7` explains this in detail, but it appears to be quite messy from the [UnitsPolicy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy).

Answer (score 3):

A *kilobyte* is 1000 bytes (SI prefix meaning thousand). A *kibibyte* is 1024 bytes (IEC prefix meaning kilo binary).

This convention has been used since 1998, but I guess the usage of these prefixes are not as known as they should be.

This is also why a 1 TB (terabyte) harddisk is only 0.91 TiB (tebibytes, as reported by the filesystem).

A related issue is when authors state that a number is given in *"kbytes"*. Since this is not an official declaration, you don't know if they mean one or the other.

Since the `ulimit` help page says: *"Values are in 1024-byte increments"*, I believe it is safe to assume that they do in fact mean *kibibytes* when they write *kbytes*.

On the other hand, since `man time` explicitly states that values are in *kilobytes*, one would have to assume that the authors are aware what a kilobyte is, and that they do in fact mean 1000 bytes.

In any case however, to be 100% certain that the authors haven't written anything that is explicitly wrong, you should check the sourcecode or consult the author of the program.

*References:*

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte
- https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html

Comment: That is not exactly what I am asking. I ask how many bytes is in the unit used by `time` and `ulimit`. From the Wikipedia page you linked: "in some areas of information technology, particularly in reference to solid-state memory capacity, kilobyte instead typically refers to 1024 (210) bytes."

Comment: And this quote is only stating, that some hardware vendors use the units wrongly...

Comment: I can agree. The question is whether `time` and `ulimit` use it properly (1000) or wrongly (1024)?

Comment: @ArturMeinild this is not the best answer possible - that would be checking the source code like you said.

Comment: No need. It's already listed in the accepted answer.

Comment: Maybe the convention is known but rejected.